# How to perform this feature in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm a novice using MVC4 with JQUERY and AJAX.

Please watch the following image where I have a hyperlink called `More`.

[image]

That hyperlink, should add another input[text] and a radiobutton. I don't know how to implement this feature, should I have to make an ajax call to add a new item to the `List<T>` and update the view? Or should I have to do everything in client side?

I just want to know ideas about how to implement it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an AJAX call to a controller action that will return a partial view with the contents of a single row. There are a couple of issues you might encounter. The most difficult part is generating correct names for your input fields so that the model binder is able to properly construct your model collection when the form is submitted. There's a specific [`naming convention`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) you need to respect.

Take a look at the [`following article`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) which explains all this in details. It also presents a custom `Html.BeginCollectionItem` helper which takes care of generating proper names for the input fields in the partial so that the naming convention is respected. It uses non-sequential index names.

Comment: Do you *really* have to hit the server for a client-side issue?

Comment: @Mark, it's much easier, as the server will take care of generating the proper markup. Not to mention things like validation, etc... which will be handled as well. You could of course do it with plain javascript as well if you prefer. No problem with that.

Comment: Another reminder why I've moved to pure JS frameworks (client+server). MVC can't generate JavaScript templates can it? If you could compile a Razor template into a JS function, that would be sweet.

Comment: Mark, but why would you need MVC to generate you javascript templates when it can directly generate you the correct markup? It seems to me a bit of a waste when I see people querying an ASP.NET MVC action which returns some complex JSON and then using a client side template to turn that JSON into HTML and inject it into the DOM, when the controller action could directly return you the desired markup (a partial view) with additional benefit of strongly typed helpers, correct names for your input fields, validation error messages, ... All that's left on the client is `$('#div').html(result);`.

Comment: For initial page load that's great, but you're making it so that for every action every user ever performs they're sending a request to the server and then waiting for a response back. You're adding latency to every action, and if your site gets big, you're making the server do a lot more processing and wasting bandwidth. You would still get all that type safety if MVC transparently generated the JS for you -- you'd still be working in C# and Razor. You should be doing client-side validation anyway (which I know MVC actually *does* support).